# NVL, SUBSTR, and RPAD syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, substr, nvl

I am trying to create a fixed width file by selecting the values like so:

```
SELECT distinct SubStr(RPad(InitCap(p.namelast),50,' '),1,50)
|| SubStr(RPad(InitCap(p.namefirst),50,' '),1,50)
|| SubStr(RPad(p.house ||' ' || p.street || ' '  ||p.streettype,50,' '),1,50)
||'                                                  ' 
||SubStr(RPad(InitCap(p.city),35,' '),1,35)
||NVL(SubStr(RPad(p.province,2,'0'),1,2),'  ')
||NVL(SubStr(RPad(p.postal,5,'0'),1,5),'     ')
```

The above works fine. However, I also need to account for the fact that the address will either be parsed in the fields I have above (p.house, p.street, p.streettype...) or be found in ADDRESS1 and ADDRESS2. ADDRESS 2 however contains city state and zip and will need to be parsed.

Can I accomplish this by using an NVL? I feel like if I use an NVL and SUBSTR the values out that I need, It could work. But I'm not sure of the syntax.

Data in ADDRESS1 and ADDRESS2 looks like this respectively:

```
123 boom drive|MONTGOMERY AL 45777
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure what you're asking for, but if this is about formatting all these columns consistently, one approach would be to format the columns instead of using subsets and padding. For example:

```
column Address1 format a20 ;
column Address2 format a20 ; 
column aliased-column format a20;
```

This keeps your select statement a whole lot cleaner and more maintainable. Getting more fancy, you could create a script that dynamically formats the columns in your table(s). For example:

```
select 'column ' || table_name || ' format a20; ' from all_tables where lower(owner) = 'scott';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need `SUBSTR`. the `RPAD` keyword truncates for you already.
2. for your `NVL` use something like the following. if the concat of `house`, `street`, `streettype` is `NULL` then it will use `address1||address2`

```sql
    || NVL(
            RPAD(p.house||' '||p.street||' '||p.streettype,50,' ')
          , RPAD(address1||' '||address2,50,' ')
          )
```

3. for more complicated string parsing, read the Oracle references for `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `CASE WHEN`
4. if you're dealing with several possible `NULL` columns then use `COALESCE`; it's more powerful than `NVL`